# Different ways to check whether an eigenvalue equals a real number?

Tags: r, complex-numbers, eigenvalue

I have the following matrix

```
M <- structure(c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), .Dim = c(5L, 5L))
```

I want to find the eigenvalues that are exactly 1. I thought this would work:

```
Re(eigen(M)$values) == 1 & Im(eigen(M)$values) == 0
```

but `Re(eigen(M)$values) == 1` doesn't think the 5th eigenvalues equals 1, even though it does. What am I missing?

EDIT: As soon as it's pointed out as a floating point problem, I investigate a bit more and find out about several solution, including using `abs(value) < tol`, `all.equal`, and `signif`. Could an answer discuss these options?

Comment: Could be the float issue like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal)

Comment: On my computer, `Re(eigen(M)$values)[5]` gives `0.9999999999999997779554` with `options(digits = 22)`.

Comment: Because `format(Re(eigen(M)$values[c(3, 5)]), digits=22)
[1] "1.0000000000000000000000" "0.9999999999999997779554"`

Comment: Another way could be `Re(eigen(M)$values) %%1 == 0 & Im(eigen(M)$values) %% 1 == 0`, which give `FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In R, the usual way to deal with floating-point numbers in the case of comparisons like `==` is to use the function `all.equal()`.

You may want to try:

```
sapply(1:nrow(M), function(x) identical(all.equal(eigen(M)$values[x],1+0i),TRUE))
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

There are often workarounds that lead to the same result (`round`, `signif`...), but using `all.equal()` is preferable since it is a function that is designed to handle comparisons of floating point numbers, without the need to tweak accuracy thresholds or to specify the number of significant digits.

As stated in `?Comparison`:

> For numerical and complex values, remember == and != do not allow for the finite representation of fractions, nor for rounding error. Using all.equal with identical is almost always preferable.

Comment: Could you explain why this is the preferred way in R?

Comment: But aren't the results wrong? It should be `FALSE  FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  FALSE`.

Comment: They look look good to me. According to my computer the fourth eigenvalue is (-1+0i). If that one should be included in the `TRUE` list, too; then one may need to add `abs()` somewhere.

Comment: But it is a real. It should be included. But not the fifth, as already showed in the comments.

Comment: `Re(eigen(M)$values)` yields `-0.5 -0.5 1.0 -1.0 1.0`. According to the OP one of the conditions is that only the values with a real value equal to 1 should be included, if I understood the question correctly. The third and the fifth value fulfill this condition within the accuracy of floating-point calculations, but the fourth doesn't.

Comment: But the real part of the fifth element is not equal to 1.

Comment: @Pascal  Analytically the fifth eigenvalue is equal to one. The differences you mentioned in the comment are artifacts due to floating-point arithmetics. The corresponding eigenvector is (1/sqrt(3))*(-1,-1,-1,0,0)^T.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to use `abs`; this has to do w/ float point precision:

```
abs(Re(eigen(M)$values) - 1) < .001
```

Comment: "Using" `abs` is only a means to the end, not the reason (or only solution) to such.

Comment: I'd appreciate it if the answerer discusses the pro / con of several solutions for floating point in R as listed in the edit.